# How do I write a unit test to my class by reading a file and writing it to another file?

Tags: java, spring, testing, readfile, writefile

I need to read an xlsx file and wirte the output in combination with a SQL statement to a file.

The following are the requirements:

1. The file is located in a specific folder on the C drive.
2. in the file, the 1st and 3rd column should be read without the headers.
3. a SQL statement is to be written to a file in combination with the previous output.

This works so far. I had to implement this with JAVA8 Springboot. Enclosed I have uploaded my MainClass, the ExcelReader Class, the aapplication.properties and the pom.xml

I don't understand now how I create my unit test for it. Do I have to split my class into several methods, because in one method readInputFileWriteSQLStatements(), the file is read, the columns are filtered and a new file is filled.

Which parameters should I write into these methods?
How does the unit test look like?

FIRST TRY:

First I set the path property in the Mainclass, and put the parameter in Class ExcelReader to readInputFileWriteSQLStatements(String filePath); but the result is NULL. Then i tried to write a TestClass with a path vom the test/resource/ directory but this didnt, work beacut of the NULL Pointer exception

```
@Value("${filepath}")
private static String filePath;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

    SpringApplication sa = new SpringApplication(MainClass.class);

    ApplicationContext c = sa.run(args);
    ExcelReader bean = c.getBean(ExcelReader.class);
    bean.readInputFileWriteSQLStatements(filePath);
}
```

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@Configuration
public class ExcelReader {

    public static final String SQL_FILE_NAME = "SQL_insert_statements_for_LBU.txt";

    private static final String FILE_PATTERN = ".xlsx";

    private static final String INVALID_VALUE_IN_ROW = "invalid values in row ";
    private static final String INVALID_SOU_CODE = ": length of sou code should be less than 10";
    private static final String INVALID_LOCATION_NUMBER = ": length of location number should be less than 15";
    private static final String INSERT_WHEN_EXIST = "INSERT WHEN EXISTS ";
    private static final String SELECT_ID_FROM_M_S_WHERE_CODE = "(SELECT ID from M_S  WHERE CODE = '";
    private static final String INTO_M_S_LOC = "') THEN INTO M_S_LBU_LOC (LBU_ID, GEO_SCOPE_LOC_NUM) SELECT ";
    private static final String FROM_DUAL = "' from dual;";
    private String codes;
    private String locNumbers;
    private String insertStatement;
    @Value("${filepath}")
    private String filePath;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    public void readInputFileWriteSQLStatements() throws IOException, InvalidFormatException, IllegalArgumentException {

        File directoryPath = new File(filePath);
        File[] files = directoryPath.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.endsWith(FILE_PATTERN);
            }
        });

        File file = files[0];
        // Creating a Workbook from an Excel file (.xls or .xlsx)
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(filePath + file.getName()));

        System.out.println("NAME ===" + filePath + file.getName());

        BufferedWriter outStream = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath + SQL_FILE_NAME));

        // Getting the sheet at index zero
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        int totalRows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

        //for iterating columns ( 1. & 3. column)
        Row r = sheet.getRow(0);
        int lastColumnUsed = r.getLastCellNum();

        IntStream.range(1, totalRows).forEach(
            iteratedRows - > {

                Row rows = sheet.getRow(iteratedRows);

                IntStream.range(0, lastColumnUsed - 1).forEach(
                    iteratedColumns - > {
                        if (iteratedColumns == 0 || iteratedColumns == 2) {
                            codes = rows.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();

                            //get the location number
                            DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
                            Cell locNumbers = rows.getCell(2);
                            locationNumbers = formatter.formatCellValue(locNumbers);
                            insertStatement = .....
                        }
                    }

                );

                int lengthCodes = codes.length();
                int lengthLocationNumber = locationNumbers.length();

                try {
                    //the value of location number could be invalid and formatted like "1,000E16" -> 10000000000007800
                    //lenght ist more than 15, so I get the last two chars of location number and check if its less than 15
                    String formatLocationNumbers = locationNumbers.substring(locationNumbers.length() - 2);

                    if (lengthCodes <= 10 && lengthLocationNumber <= 15 && !locationNumbers.contains("+")) {
                        outStream.write(insertStatement);
                        outStream.newLine();
                    }
                    if ((lengthCodes <= 10) &&
                        (locationNumbers.contains("+") && Integer.parseInt(formatLocationNumbers) < 15)) {
                        outStream.write(insertStatement);
                        outStream.newLine();
                    }
                    if ((lengthCodes > 10) && (
                            (locationNumbers.contains("+") && Integer.parseInt(formatLocationNumbers) > 15) ||
                            lengthLocationNumber > 15)) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(INVALID_VALUE_IN_ROW + iteratedRows +
                            INVALID_SOU_CODE +
                            INVALID_LOCATION_NUMBER);
                    }
                    if (lengthCodes > 10) {

                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(INVALID_VALUE_IN_ROW + iteratedRows +
                            INVALID_SOU_CODE);
                    }
                    if ((lengthLocationNumber > 15) ||
                        (locationNumbers.contains("+") && Integer.parseInt(formatLocationNumbers) >= 15)) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(INVALID_VALUE_IN_ROW + iteratedRows +
                            INVALID_LOCATION_NUMBER);
                    }

                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            });

        workbook.close();
        outStream.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: The requirement matches to Spring Batch.

Answer (score 1):

You would like to re(design) or re(structure) of your implementation.

1. I would explore Spring Batch approach to see if it matches to your use case. I'm seeing in this case, Reader (Excel Reader), Processor and Writer (Database Writer) is totally working.
2. Spring Batch already has unit-test approach already. You can follow https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/testing.html
3. If you don't want to leverage Spring Batch, I would suggest you to separate the logic for Reader and Processor and Writer with Interface and Implementation so you can have better design as well as unit-test

Hope it helps.

Comment: Have you got an idea how to restructer my code? The exception handling is inside the first IntStream and contains the write() method to write the content in a file. 

The write() method contains the SQL Insertstatement, which is define in the inner IntStream

Comment: I will spend sometime to re structure your code. At work now, will do later.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things.
Generally your class ExcelReader would be considered as a service in spring and would be annotated with @Service annotation. @Configuration annotation is usually used for defining beans. Its better to keep these separate.

When writing tests we usually create a test class with the with the same name of the class + Test. In your case it would be ExcelReaderTest. Once you create the class you would create a method with @Test annotation, in your case it would be.

```
public class ExcelReaderTest {
    @Test
    public void testReadInputFileWriteSQLStatements() {

    }
}
```

Write your tests inside the method annotated with @Test annotation. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have extract the exception handling and the iteration for the columns in methods.

```
public int exceptionHandling(BufferedWriter outStream, int iteratedRows, int lengthSouCodes, int lengthLocationNumber)

public void defineColumns(int lastColumnUsed, Row rows)
```

But my unit test does not work:

> Expected: is "invalid values in row 20: length of sou code should be less than 10" but: was null
>
> Expected :is "invalid values in row 20: length of sou code should be less than 10" Actual   :null

My unit test for the first method is:

```
private ExcelReader excelReaderTest = new ExcelReader();

@Test
public void exceptionHandling() throws IOException {

    try {
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt" ));
        int lenghtLocNum = excelReaderTest.exceptionHandling(out, 20, 11, 5);
        fail();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        assertThat(e.getMessage(), is("invalid values in row " + 20 + ": length of source code should be less than 10"));
    }
}
```

ExcelReader:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@Configuration
public class ExcelReader {

    public static final String SQL_FILE_NAME = "SQL_insert_statements_for_LBU.txt";
    private static final String FILE_PATTERN = ".xlsx";

    private static final String INVALID_VALUE_IN_ROW = "invalid values in row ";
    private static final String INVALID_SOU_CODE = ": length of sou code should be less than 10";
    private static final String INVALID_LOCATION_NUMBER = ": length of location number should be less than 15";
    private static final String INSERT_WHEN_EXIST = "INSERT WHEN EXISTS ";
    private static final String SELECT_ID_FROM_MD_SOU_WHERE_SOU_CODE = "(SELECT ID from MD_SOU  WHERE SOU_CODE = '";
    private static final String INTO_MD_SOU_LOCATION = "') THEN INTO MD_SOU_LBU_LOCATION (LBU_ID, GEO_SCOPE_LOCATION_NUMBER) SELECT ";
    private static final String FROM_DUAL = "' from dual;";
    private String souCodes;
    private String locationNumbers;
    private String insertStatement;
    @Value("${filepath}")
    private String filePath;

    @Value("${outputfilepath}")
    private String outputFilePath;

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    public void readInputFileWriteSQLStatements() throws IOException, InvalidFormatException, IllegalArgumentException {

        File directoryPath = new File(filePath);
        File[] files = directoryPath.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.endsWith(FILE_PATTERN);
            }
        });

        File file = files[0];
        // Creating a Workbook from an Excel file (.xls or .xlsx)
        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(filePath + file.getName()));

        System.out.println("NAME ===" + filePath + file.getName());

        BufferedWriter outStream = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFilePath + SQL_FILE_NAME));

        // Getting the sheet at index zero
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        int totalRows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

        //for iterating columns ( 1. & 3. column)
        Row r = sheet.getRow(0);
        int lastColumnUsed = r.getLastCellNum();

        IntStream.range(1, totalRows).forEach(
                iteratedRows -> {

                    Row rows = sheet.getRow(iteratedRows);

                    defineColumns(lastColumnUsed, rows);

                    int lengthSouCodes = souCodes.length();
                    int lengthLocationNumber = locationNumbers.length();

                    exceptionHandling(outStream, iteratedRows, lengthSouCodes, lengthLocationNumber);


                });

        workbook.close();
        outStream.flush();
    }

    public int exceptionHandling(BufferedWriter outStream, int iteratedRows, int lengthSouCodes, int lengthLocationNumber) {
        try {
            //the value of location number could be invalid and formatted like "1,000E16" -> 10000000000007800
            //lenght ist more than 15, so I get the last two chars of location number and check if its less than 15
            String formatLocationNumbers = locationNumbers.substring(locationNumbers.length() - 2);

            if (lengthSouCodes <= 10 && lengthLocationNumber <= 15 && !locationNumbers.contains("+")) {
                outStream.write(insertStatement);
                outStream.newLine();
            }
            if ((lengthSouCodes <= 10) &&
                    (locationNumbers.contains("+") && Integer.parseInt(formatLocationNumbers) < 15)) {
                outStream.write(insertStatement);
                outStream.newLine();
            }
            if ((lengthSouCodes > 10) && (
                    (locationNumbers.contains("+") && Integer.parseInt(formatLocationNumbers) > 15)
                            || lengthLocationNumber > 15)
            ) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(INVALID_VALUE_IN_ROW + iteratedRows +
                                                           INVALID_SOU_CODE +
                                                           INVALID_LOCATION_NUMBER);
            }
            if (lengthSouCodes > 10) {

                throw new IllegalArgumentException(INVALID_VALUE_IN_ROW + iteratedRows
                                                           + INVALID_SOU_CODE);
            }
            if ((lengthLocationNumber > 15) ||
                    (locationNumbers.contains("+") && Integer.parseInt(formatLocationNumbers) >= 15)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(INVALID_VALUE_IN_ROW + iteratedRows
                                                           + INVALID_LOCATION_NUMBER);
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 0;
    }

    public void defineColumns(int lastColumnUsed, Row rows) {
        IntStream.range(0, lastColumnUsed - 1).forEach(
                iteratedColumns -> {


                    if (iteratedColumns == 0 || iteratedColumns == 2) {
                        souCodes = rows.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();

                        //get the location number
                        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
                        Cell locNumbers = rows.getCell(2);
                        locationNumbers = formatter.formatCellValue(locNumbers);
                        insertStatement =
                                INSERT_WHEN_EXIST
                                        + SELECT_ID_FROM_MD_SOU_WHERE_SOU_CODE
                                        + souCodes
                                        + INTO_MD_SOU_LOCATION
                                        + SELECT_ID_FROM_MD_SOU_WHERE_SOU_CODE
                                        + souCodes
                                        + "'),  '"
                                        + locationNumbers
                                        + FROM_DUAL;
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating the instance of ExcelReader using new keyword, all the fields are null. You should get ExcelReader from the spring container so that all the fields are autowired by spring when the instance is created.